# TFS 2010 Report Unit Number of Unit Tests Passed / Failed

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, tfsbuild

Does anyone know of a link describing how to create a TFS 2010 query or report showing number of unit tests run / passed / failed for a particular automated build over a period of time?